# show pop up when trying to add a duplicate record to the database

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Is there anyway that I could show a pop up when the user tries to enter a record which already exists in the database?
Right now the user will be redirected to the Index View when he submits data which already exist in the database. 
Here is the current code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Product product)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if(DQL.DuplicateCheck(product))
        {
            // This is what I want to change
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            db.Product.Add(product);
            db.SaveChanges();
            TempData["product_model"] = product;
            return RedirectToAction("Product", "Success");

        }

    }

    return View(product);
}
```

I searched now for a while but didn't found anything appropriate. Any help is highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jquery ui dialog you can achieve this. Add a TempData flag for duplication check and do the same in view using jQuery and display the popup window.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Product product)
    {
        TempData["Duplicate"] = null;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if(DQL.DuplicateCheck(product))
            {
                TempData["Duplicate"] = "Yes";
            }
            else
            {
                db.Product.Add(product);
                db.SaveChanges();
                TempData["product_model"] = product;
                return RedirectToAction("Product", "Success");

            }

        }

        return View(product);
    }
```

### Create.cshtml or CreateView

```
<div id="dialog-message" title="Message">
        <p id="validMessage">
        </p>
    </div>

$(function () {

 $("#dialog-message").dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        resizable: false,
        width: 400,
        buttons: { Ok: function () {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
        }
    });
   var isDuplicate = '@TempData["Duplicate"]';
   if(isDuplicate == 'Yes')
   {
     $("#validMessage").html("Duplicate record found");
     $("#dialog-message").dialog('open');
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you added below jquery assets files jquery-1.9.1.min.js,
jquery/jquery-ui.js, jquery/jquery-ui.css

Comment: Yes i did that, but the problem was something else. But now i fixed it. Thank you very much :)